# Zesty: trying to install Eclipse for Java development

Tags: java, eclipse

Im rtying to install eclipse for java development, but I get an error, when using the repo, or installing from source, it appear to be the same error, and I do not understand the context to be able to address the problem.

Here is what the log says, what is the issue? how do I install eclipse for java?

OS:Ubuntu Mate 17.04

```
!SESSION 2017-12-01 16:45:04.982 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=debbuild
java.version=9-Ubuntu
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-12-01 16:45:13.282
!MESSAGE error loading hook: org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseHookConfigurator
!STACK 0
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected void java.net.URLClassLoader.addURL(java.net.URL) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.net" to unnamed module @60c6f5b
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:335)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:278)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:196)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.findMethod(BaseStorage.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.findMethod(BaseStorage.java:181)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.findAddURLMethod(BaseStorage.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.<init>(BaseStorage.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseHookConfigurator.addHooks(BaseHookConfigurator.java:24)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.HookRegistry.loadConfigurators(HookRegistry.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.HookRegistry.initialize(HookRegistry.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.BaseAdaptor.<init>(BaseAdaptor.java:98)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.createAdaptor(EclipseStarter.java:737)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:176)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:547)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-12-01 16:45:13.343
!MESSAGE Startup error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.BaseAdaptor.initializeStorage(BaseAdaptor.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.<init>(Framework.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:176)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:547)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to install Ecilpse with [Ubuntu Make](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-make):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-make
umake ide eclipse
```